# How to always run the project instead of displayed file (.aspx), with F5, in VS10, when building af website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way in VS10 to set the F5 key, so VS *always* runs the projekt (e.g. default.aspx) and not the open .aspx page I am currently working on?

It could really save me alot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on that `default.aspx` file and choose "Set as Start Page"

[image]

or, you can set in the Project Property Page (Shift + F4)

[image]

Comment: Specific page, just what I was looking for. I took it for granted that I did not have to specify any page as long as I told the start up project. But this did the job. Thanks alot, and thanks alot for all the answers guys.

Answer (score 3):

Right click `default.aspx` and select `Set as Start Page`.

See [here](http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/06/26/tip-84-did-you-know-how-to-set-a-start-page-for-your-web-site-in-visual-web-developer.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In case of web - application or website you can do that in two ways

1). In solution explorer selected the intended page (eg default.aspx) and right click and click on "Set as Start Page"

2). In solution explorer right click on project and properties > Web tab > In "Start Action" - Specific page and find the page and select it.

after that whenever you hit F5 you will always start with that page only and not the one that is open and in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Just rightclick i.e Default.aspx and choose "Set as Start Page"

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, right click on the file you want to start with and select "Set as Start Page".

Answer (score 0):

if you  want to  set your current page right click on current page in solution explorer - and choose  "Set as startup item"